# WCF Data Service 5.6 + EF 6 Code First + Alpha Provider with Stream Provide

Tags: wcf, stream, wcf-data-services, entity-framework-6, provider

I need some help please. I've tried to implement a stream provider along with EntityFrameworkDataService Provider. I, then, implemented IServiceProvider on my Data Service as it's recommended in this [series of article about StreamProvider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2010/08/04/data-services-streaming-provider-series-implementing-a-streaming-provider-part-1.aspx).

But I'm not able to set up the CSDL file (HasStream Attribute) in code first to suit the needs for having a Service Type StreamProvider enabled.

Is There something I messed up or a way to register properly my StreamProvider with EF6 Code First ? Does I have to implement a MetadaServiceProvider ?

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information,
I tried to use HasTreamAttribute on my entity and this did not work because IDataServiceProvider was not enumerated into GetService Method implementation of IServiceProvider. 
Then, I resolve it by applying **[NamedStream("StreamLink")]**  on my entity, and I was able to intercept IDataServiceStreamProvider2 into GetService Implementation of IServiceProvider.

Hope it helps !